# Generics on properties Kotlin

Tags: kotlin, generics

Im trying to find a better way to say that a property `list` of the class `MyList` instances should be of any class that extends `List<MyItem>`, so start with this:

```
class MyItem {

}
abstract class MyList {
    abstract val list: List<MyItem>
    abstract fun first(): MyItem
}

class MyLinkedList: MyList() {
    override val list: List<MyItem> = LinkedList<MyItem>()
    override fun first(): MyItem {
        return (list as LinkedList<MyItem>).first
    }
}

class MyArrayList: MyList() {
    override val list: List<MyItem> = ArrayList()
    override fun first(): MyItem {
        return list[0]
    }
}
```

This would be OK though i really hate that `(list as LinkedList<MyItem>)` casting because in my real use case its going to make the code not readable nor maintainable (as it is much more complex then that simple example, now the second attempt which is already better is here:

```
class MyItem {

}
abstract class MyList<WrappedList: List<MyItem>> {
    abstract val list: WrappedList
    abstract fun first(): MyItem
}

class MyLinkedList: MyList<LinkedList<MyItem>>() {
    override val list = LinkedList<MyItem>()
    override fun first(): MyItem {
        return list.first
    }
}

class MyArrayList: MyList<ArrayList<MyItem>>() {
    override val list = ArrayList<MyItem>()
    override fun first(): MyItem {
        return list[0]
    }
}
```

So this is quite nice, but in my use case, in this approach im gonna end up doing :

```
abstract class MyList<
        WrappedList1: List<MyItem1>,
        WrappedList2: List<MyItem2>,
        ...
        WrappedListN: List<MyItemN>
        > {
    abstract val list1: WrappedList1
    abstract val list2: WrappedList2
    ...
    abstract val listn: WrappedListN
    ...
}
```

Although it does what i want it to do, it looks a bit repetitive and redundant, it feels like there should be something similiar to:

```
 abstract class MyList {
    abstract val list1: extends List<MyItem1>
    abstract val list2: extends List<MyItem2>
    ...
    abstract val listn: extends List<MyItemN>
    ...
}
```

That is create the "extends" anonymous in place instead of naming so many generic types.

Is there a way to do that?

Comment: Short answer, no. Long answer, Kotlin does not support such a feature out of the box, but, with the fact that compiler plugins can be written, it may be possible to write a compiler plugin that converts your psuedo code, into valid code.

Comment: If I understand what you are asking, Kotlin already does this out of the box. You can *already* do `override val list = LinkedList<MyItem>()`, and `list` will be of type `LinkedList` in your concrete class, without a `WrappedList` type parameter.

Answer (score 2):

> Im trying to find a better way to say that a property list of the class MyList instances should be of any class that extends List

Well, a property of type `List<MyItem>` really means exactly that already. No need for more syntax. This is Liskov's substitution principle - you should be able to use any instance that conforms to the contract of `List<MyItem>` as a value of this property.

> This would be OK though i really hate that (list as LinkedList) casting

You don't have to cast. The solution depends on what you're trying to achieve. You seem to change your goal half-way through the question.

If you "just" want to be able to use your concrete list type in the implementation of your class, then just use a separate (private) property of that concrete type and use the overridden property to expose it as the parent type:

```kotlin
abstract class MyList {
    abstract val list: List<MyItem>
    abstract fun first(): MyItem
}

class MyLinkedList: MyList() {
    private val _list = LinkedList<MyItem>()
    override val list: List<MyItem> = _list
    
    override fun first(): MyItem {
        return _list.first
    }
}

class MyArrayList: MyList() {
    private val _list = ArrayList<MyItem>()
    override val list: List<MyItem> = _list
    override fun first(): MyItem {
        return list[0]
    }
}
```

Now, if you also don't mind exposing that new type outside the class, it's even simpler, you just declare your overridden property as being of a subtype of the parent property's type:

```kotlin
abstract class MyList {
    abstract val list: List<MyItem>
    abstract fun first(): MyItem
}

class MyLinkedList: MyList() {
    override val list: LinkedList<MyItem> = LinkedList<MyItem>()
    override fun first(): MyItem {
        return list.first
    }
}

class MyArrayList: MyList() {
    override val list: ArrayList<MyItem> = ArrayList()
    override fun first(): MyItem {
        return list[0]
    }
}
```